# React / NextJS: Duplicated Audiowave element

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, wavesurfer.js

I'm building a `messenger application` in `NextJS` with a TTS functionality. In order to visualize the waveform of the audio being played, I'm using a third-party library called `wavesurfer.js`

While the implementation and audio playing works fine, my current approach renders two `<wave>` elements, only one of which is technically functioning, which is breaking the UI layout.

[image]

Manually removing the redundant `<wave>` file with the browser inspection tool shows the correct display of the component a sit should be, but I can't identify what is responsible for the redundant generation of another `<wave>` element.

[image]

**Which segment of my code is causing the redundant rendering?**

```
import Image from 'next/image';
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';

import Conor from '@/public/assets/images/user.jpeg';

import PauseIcon from './PauseIcon';
import PlayIcon from './PlayIcon';

interface ChatBubbleProps {
  trackDuration: string;
  trackUrl: string;
}

function ChatBubble(props: ChatBubbleProps) {
  const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false);
  const waveformRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const waveSurferRef = useRef<WaveSurfer | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadWaveSurfer = async () => {
      const { default: WaveSurfer } = await import('wavesurfer.js');
      if (props.trackUrl) {
        waveSurferRef.current = WaveSurfer.create({
          container: waveformRef.current,
          waveColor: 'white',
          progressColor: '#00000',
          cursorWidth: 0,
          cursorColor: 'transparent',
        });

        if (props.trackUrl) {
          waveSurferRef.current.load(props.trackUrl);
        }
      }
    };

    loadWaveSurfer();
  }, [props.trackUrl]);

  const handlePlayPauseClick = () => {
    setIsPlaying(!isPlaying);
    if (waveSurferRef.current) {
      waveSurferRef.current.playPause();
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="py-4">
      <div className="flex">
        <div className="mt-auto flex h-12 w-12 -space-x-1 overflow-hidden rounded-full ">
          <Image src={User} alt="User Name" />
        </div>
        <div className="ml-4 flex h-16 w-72 items-center justify-center rounded-full bg-gradient-to-r from-rose-600 via-fuchsia-500 to-indigo-500 px-8 py-2">
          <div className="gap-8">
            <div onClick={handlePlayPauseClick}>
              {isPlaying ? <PlayIcon /> : <PauseIcon />}
            </div>
          </div>
          <div
            className="relative ml-4 w-72 items-center"
            ref={waveformRef}
          ></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ChatBubble;
```

Comment: You may want to make sure the wavesurfer initialization effect is run only on the client.

Comment: Thanks - can you further elaborate on that, please?

Comment: See https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import#with-no-ssr maybe – I haven't been following Next.js lately so I'm not sure if there's some other officially sanctioned way to do this, but the point is you'd want the external library to only initialize once, and to do it only on the client even if Next would prerender stuff on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

modify your useEffect by adding if clause for !waveSurferRef?.current will fix you issue like this

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
    const loadWaveSurfer = async () => {
      const { default: WaveSurfer } = await import('wavesurfer.js')
      if (file && waveformRef?.current && !waveSurferRef.current) {
        waveSurferRef.current = WaveSurfer.create({
          container: waveformRef?.current,
          waveColor: 'white',
          progressColor: '#00000',
          cursorWidth: 0,
          cursorColor: 'transparent',
          barWidth: 3,
          barGap: 2,
          barRadius: 3,
          height: 50,
        })

        if (file) {
          waveSurferRef?.current?.load(file)
        }
      }
    }

    loadWaveSurfer()
  }, [waveSurferRef, file])
```